# Cmd disappears during working without any message

Tags: windows, command-line, streaming

My program is written in python3.

It uses `streamlink` library to download multiple streamings as each of them turns on and until turns off (so that I use `threading` for multi-processing).

When I run this program on my laptop, it works very well. Each of those streamings turns on pretty randomly. I turn on my laptop, open my `cmd`, lower the brightness as much as I can, run the program and I go sleep. When I wake up, everything is done as I expect. (I will move on to VM later on, but now the point is that it works on my laptop.)

But when I try this on my desktop, `cmd` sometimes disappears. More specifically, it disappears about 20~30 minutes after **a** streaming has been downloaded. I'm saying that `cmd` itself just vanishes. I can't turn this `cmd` on, but I can see that it runs in the background (using task manager or `tasklist` in another `cmd`). But this program will not be able to catch another streaming turned on once it vanishes.

So it's a real pain. I can't find anything similar to this cause once I search with the keyword 'vanish' or 'disappear', everything is related to something immediate. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

1. I did format my desktop recently. I'm pretty much sure that my computer is clean (no messy `PATH` and so on..).
2. I turned off every option regarding power options. i.e. never becomes energy-save mode or stand-by mode.

Comment: 1. Does Alt-Tab make it pop up again? 2. Perform usual repairs with SFC and DISM in case there's a defective OS file.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 1. Definitely not, I can't find it anywhere it really literally disappears. 2. I will search and try it. Thank you!

Comment: Just to record, same symptom happens on my laptop! Still don't know why, I did SFC with no defective OS file. I suspected some vaccines but maybe that's not the case because I ran the program using pycharm instead of cmd and pycharm doesn't disappear. So that's my workaround. I changed some options of cmd earlier because of the cursor problem, maybe that's why?